Using RAND() function and solver add-in a monte carlo simulation into excel for a portfolio of 5 stocks
I want to run a monte carlo simulation into excel for a portfolio of 5 stocks and I want to find the necessary weights for each stock to maximize the Sharpe ratio, but because I'm using the rand() function, I think that the solver add-in it doesn't working correctly. Please, can you give me some ways to face this issue? Thank you!
I tried to use them at the same time, but it didn't work
